# Rails setting parameters to nil after removed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a rails project in my users model I have a bunch of optional attributes for user.  If a user adds a attribute saves it to the database then removes it later it is saved to the database as an empty string, not nil.  Is there any way to set the value back to nil if a user decides to delete an attribute from their profile, without having to manually do it in the controller?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this for text fields, but I suppose it could happen for other String values, etc. One approach would be to override the setter for your optional attribute(s). Such as:

```
# Do this for each attribute:
def my_attr=(value)
  super(value.presence)
end
```

Assuming you're setting the optional attributes in your controller straight-up or using Rails' mass-assignment... this should make sure the string is not `blank?` before setting the internal attributes (and if it is it will set the attribute to `nil` instead).

Another option is to setup a `before_save` method to check and set any `blank?` values to nil. But I think the attribute method override would be preferred as it's more explicit.